# The following palindrome test in java netbeans is giving a wrong answer for the "if statement". Please tell the mistake

Tags: java, netbeans

the following java application was made by a JFrame form.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
 Integer number = Integer.parseInt(t.getText());
```

// t is the text box in which text is entered

```
while(number > 0)

{

Integer q = number%10;
Integer number1= (number-q);
number = number1/10;
ans.append("" + q);
```

//ans is text area in which reversed number is shown

```
}

number = Integer.parseInt(t.getText()); 
Integer answer  = Integer.parseInt(ans.getText());
Double a = (double) answer;

if(number == answer)
{

System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
}
else{System.out.println("not a palindrome");}
}
```

Comment: Indent your code with 4 spaces when you post it here.

Comment: You should not use reference type Integer unless you specifically need a to reference the said number. Use int instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` is a child class of Object, wrapping the primitive `int` type.
You are comparing at the end whether two Integer object are identical, not whether the integer values are equal.

The code would normally be written as:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    int number = Integer.parseInt(t.getText());

    // t is the text box in which text is entered
    while (number > 0) {
        int q = number % 10;
        number = number1 / 10;
        ans.append("" + q);

        //ans is text area in which reversed number is shown
    }

    number = Integer.parseInt(t.getText()); 
    int answer  = Integer.parseInt(ans.getText());
    if (number == answer) {
        System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Note: `/` is here the *integer division* which discards the remainder automatically.

```
Type     Class
----     -----
int      Integer
double   Double
boolean  Boolean
long     Long
byte     Byte
short    Short
char     Character
float    Float
```